# How can i add a Expandable listview to the end of a page in a scrollview?

Tags: android, listview, height, adapter, expandable

I need to place an expandable listview to the end of a page that displays some data in a scrollview. Basically the listview contains some user comments for the page. The page contains a lot of dynamic data so that it can be placed in a scrollview only. When i add an expandable listview to the end of the scrollview it falls in the right position. But when i expand the listview & set the parent view to wrap height, a part of the listview get clipped of. How can i handle this. I have tried setting the layoutparams of Parent view to wrap content. But that doesnt work.
PS: The cell sizes of the expandable list items is variable.
EDIT: The structure of my xml is

```
ScrollView
       LinearLayout  
               Comments layout is inflated here along with some other layouts
```

Comment layout is

```
               LinearLayout
                    Expandablelistview
```

I am tring to set the sizes of parent layout dynamically after calculating in onExpanded & collapsed

Comment: listview don't really like being in a scrollview. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing )

Comment: So any solutions to adjust the view heights to fit the content ?